# iOS ES 2 render from RAM OK, verts in VBO OK but with indices in BO fails

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm extending the Xcode opengles template, got rid of the virtual es1 stuff.
Now I managed to render my model from RAM both vertexArray and indexArray,
then I managed to gen-,bind-,dataBuffer the vertexArray VBO and changed the regular RAM-pointers to offset-pointers.
This all works fine, however the next phase to place the indexAray in a BO and gen-,bind-,dataBuffer and change the RAM-pointers to offset-pointers fails :(

Are there any common pitfalls I haven't notice, to me anyone able to make a VBO should be able to make an indexArray-buffer...

The following code is done in the setupGL

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &geometryPtr->vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryPtr->vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(geometryPtr->vertexNormalUV), geometryPtr->vertexNormalUV, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //
    glGenBuffers(1, &geometryPtr->vertexIndicesBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryPtr->vertexIndicesBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(geometryPtr->indices), geometryPtr->indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then the basic idea in the render routine

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryPtr->vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryPtr->vertexIndicesBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    //
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, trianglesCount*3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void *)offset);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, triangleStripOffsets[m], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void *)offset);
```

Please help? :)
Niels

Comment: I solved it (and the "Look mommy, no hands" raises....)

Comment: For the record, I solved  it, getting rid of the sizeof() function, I use my own memory manager, and though the lowercase sizeof is a runtime function, doing it immediate e.g. geometryPtr->indicesCount*2 works like charm :)

Comment: If you'd like, you could write an answer to that regard and accept it, so that the question is marked as being answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered the question in the comments, following the suggestion of Mr. Larson I will supply an (official) answer to close the question.

To elude further, I basically assumed sizeof() would make the system ask the system-memory-manager to ask the size, assigned to the pointer send...

Niels

Ps.
Thanks Mr. Larson.